# How would one Regex Match only the first few characters of a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I got these strings:

`P 1 (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833`

`A1 AMBU 18177 Binnendams 3373AE Hardinxveld-Giessendam HARDGD bon 81505`

`Prio 4(DIA: ja) AMBU 17104 F. Bordewijkstraat 3069WB Rotterdam ROTTDM bon 29230`

I've written the following regex to test on them:

```
^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?
```

How would I be able to only test the first 8 characters of this string? I've tried the following:

```py
import re

str_to_test = "P 1 (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833"
expr = re.compile(r"^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?", re.IGNORECASE)
result = re.sub(expr, '', str_to_test);
print(result) #  (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833
```

But this does the entire string, which is not what I want. I've tried changing `str_to_test` to `str_to_test[:8]` to get the first 8 characters, but this removes the rest which I also need. Please help me out here.

**The output I would like to see:**

`P 1 (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833` -> `(BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833`

`A1 AMBU 18177 Binnendams 3373AE Hardinxveld-Giessendam HARDGD bon 81505` -> `AMBU 18177 Binnendams 3373AE Hardinxveld-Giessendam HARDGD bon 81505`

`Prio 4 (DIA: ja) AMBU 17104 F. Bordewijkstraat 3069WB Rotterdam ROTTDM bon 29230` -> `(DIA: ja) AMBU 17104 F. Bordewijkstraat 3069WB Rotterdam ROTTDM bon 29230`

Comment: Could you please add the expected output from the 3 strings you provide as example, please?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Sure, a moment please

Comment: So you want to remove the first part, which matches the regex `^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?`?

Comment: @Anakhand correct, the first part mostly occurs in the first 8 characters of the string

Comment: The pattern for the 3rd needs fixing

Comment: @CeliusStingher That was in there by mistake, I removed it, my bad

Comment: Kindly see my answer, I believe it helps you with the issue, leave a comment there if there's something missing/incorrect please.

Comment: can you just do `re.sub(expr, '', str_to_test[:8]) + str_to_test[8:]` ?  EDIT: looks like there is an answer saying the same thing, which you have accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slices, change:

```
result = re.sub(expr, '', str_to_test);
```

To:

```
result = re.sub(expr, '', str_to_test[:8])+str_to_test[8:];
```

---

---

To get a better insight as to how the slices works:

```
a = '1234567890'

print(a[:8], a[8:])
```

Output:

```
12345678 90
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for, I've tried something like this but I didn't get it to work, thank you!

Comment: @Nurfey you should lose that redundant semicolon, while you are at it -- I am guessing that it is force of habit from programming in C or similar?

Comment: @alaniwi correct, I just used stack overflow as the IDE so no syntax highlight, oops!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to extract slices and reconstruct the string afterwards; you can extract whatever you want within a single regex match. You can enclose the part of the string you're interested in within a capturing group:

```
(?:^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?)\s*(?P<main>.*)
```

The first group, `(?:^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?)`, which is the part that you want to discard, is non-capturing, while the part of the string that you're interested in, which is whatever comes after it, is enclosed in the named group `(?P<main>.*)`.

Thus, to extract it, you match the above pattern to the whole string and then extract the group named `main`:

```py
import re

str_to_test = "P 1 (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833"
pattern = re.compile(r"(?:^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^PRIO\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?)\s*(?P<main>.*)", re.IGNORECASE)
match = pattern.match(str_to_test)
result = match.group("main")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
(BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to quick replacement you can use `re.sub()`. Once you define the pattern, and create a list with all the strings you wish to work on, you can ue a list comprehension to address the issue:

```
import re
strings = ['P 1 (BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833',
           'A1 AMBU 18177 Binnendams 3373AE Hardinxveld-Giessendam HARDGD bon 81505',
           'Prio 4(DIA: ja) AMBU 17104 F. Bordewijkstraat 3069WB Rotterdam ROTTDM bon 29230']
pattern = re.compile(r'^[ABP]\s?\d{1,3}|^Prio\s?[1-5]|^\d{1,3}e?')
strings_clean = [re.sub(pattern,'',x).strip() for x in strings]
```

This outputs:

```
['(BNN-03) Voertuig te water Curacaostraat Groningen 011810 011871 013593 011833',
 'AMBU 18177 Binnendams 3373AE Hardinxveld-Giessendam HARDGD bon 81505',
 '(DIA: ja) AMBU 17104 F. Bordewijkstraat 3069WB Rotterdam ROTTDM bon 29230']
```

Edit: I changed the pattern a bit because it didn't capture the third item in the list to generate the expected output.